# AS3 - Thumbnail generator

Tags: actionscript-3

I've a MovieClip with 10 frames and a photo (1024x768 px) in each frame. Now I'ld like to create a 174x174 px thumbnail from it and place it into a container (instance: thumb1 - thumb10)
How to make this happen?

Answer (score 0):

```
var mc:MovieClip = new MovieClip();
var bitmapData:BitmapData = new BitmapData(mc.width, mc.height, ... ); 
bitmapData.draw(mc);
```

then just use the bitmapData to create a Bitmap and scale it the way you like.

Answer (score -1):

Easiest way would be to create the thumbnails outside of Flash in a graphics editor (such as Photoshop or Paint.net). This would increase your file size slightly, but would probably work the best.

A simple way to do this in Flash, would be to give each image a Class linkage in the library, and just create a new instance of them when you need it. You can just set width and height (or scaleX and scaleY) on the Bitmaps to resize them, but make sure you set smoothing to true for each of them, or they wont look very nice.

Comment: How to do it with BitmapData?